# Import database through zip file

Tags: php

This is my function for downloding zip file of database it's working fine but I want to insert this in database and also import it to database by dynamic selecting sql file

```
public function db_backup(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $this->load->dbutil(); 
    $prefs = array( 
        'format' => 'zip',  
        'add_drop' => TRUE,  
        'add_insert'=> TRUE, 
        'newline' => "\n"   
    ); 
    $backup =  $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 
    $this->load->helper('file'); 
    $this->load->helper('download'); 
    $this->zip->archive(FCPATH.'backup/database/'.date('Y-m-d-His').'DbBackup.zip');
}

please provide me solution i tried vaious examples nothing works

public function restoredb($id = ''){


    $isi_file = file_get_contents('./backups/XXXXXXX.sql'); #here I want to give dynamic path
    $query = rtrim( $isi_file, "\n;" );
    $array_query = explode(";", $query);

    foreach($array_query as $query){
        $this->db->query($query);
    }

}
```

Above function restore the database but not working as I wanted

Comment: Do you have access to shell_exec in your PHP configuration?

Comment: Can you please tell how to access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$backup = read_file('path/to/file.sql');
$sql_clean = '';
    foreach (explode("\n", $backup) as $line){
        if(isset($line[0]) && $line[0] != "#"){
            $sql_clean .= $line."\n";
        }
    }
    foreach (explode(";\n", $sql_clean) as $sql){
        $sql = trim($sql);
        if($sql){
            $this->db->query($sql);
        } 
    }
```

Try this i hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try this when exporting and importing data

Export

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD -h$HOST $DATABASE > backup.sql";   
        shell_exec( $cmd );
```

Import/Restore

```
$cmd = "mysql -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD -h$HOST -D$database < backup.sql";   
        shell_exec( $cmd );
```

Comment: How to use this in codeigniter I tried it doesn't work

Comment: it display nothing except the blank screen

Comment: Try to display the error , ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(-1), I'm sure you know the basic of debugging.